# The length of spectral density is longer than the data using spectrum() in R

Tags: r, time-series, signal-processing, fourier-transform, spectral-analysis

I'm using spectrum(method = "pgram") in R to calculate the spectral density in my time series.

spectrum() returns the spectral density for each frequency(from 1/n, 2/n to 1/2, n is the time series length), that means I should get a series of spectral density with the length = n/2, and the first cycle should be n.

However, when I use the R built-in data "sunspot.month", I found the length of spectral density gets longer than the data when the data has some certain lengths.

Here is the code:

```
## Total data length = 3177 ##
length(sunspot.month)

## results are expected ##
sunspot_spec = spectrum(sunspot.month[1:400],plot = F)
length(sunspot_spec$freq)
1/sunspot_spec$freq[1]

## returned length is 864, longer cycle ##
sunspot_spec = spectrum(sunspot.month[1:1660],plot = F)
length(sunspot_spec$freq)
1/sunspot_spec$freq[1]

## returned length is 1600, longer cycle ##
sunspot_spec = spectrum(sunspot.month[1:3150],plot = F)
length(sunspot_spec$freq)
1/sunspot_spec$freq[1]
```

I didn't use any smoothing in the periodogram. I'm not sure what R is doing and why longer cycle is used.

I'm new to signal processing. Any help/comments/inputs is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please read the help page for `spec.pgram`, especially in the "Details" section beginning at "The series will be automatically padded with zeros until the series length is a highly composite number in order to help the Fast Fourier Transform."  Have you noticed that the values $864=2^53^3$ and $1600=2^65^2$ have interesting factorizations?

Comment: I see. Does that mean if I set fast = False, spec.pram() does not calculate the periodogram based on fast Fourier transform? If this is true, what kind of transform it uses? Thanks for your prompt response!

Comment: Please consult the help page: it is clear that the code uses the FFT regardless, but that the `fast` argument is intended to let you control how quickly it works.  It helps to understand the FFT algorithm: it is most efficient when the length of the vector is a "highly composite number"--best is an integral power of two.  Regardless, the FFT works for any length. More convenient software will just automatically pad your input vector with zeros, compute the FFT quickly, and then cut out the extra terms.  The authors of `spec.pgram` decided to give you more control over that process.

Comment: Got it. I need more knowledge about FFT obviously...Thank you so much for your help! This is very well-explained!

Comment: The *Numerical Recipes* book has a great explanation if you want to delve more into how the FFT works.

Comment: Thank you! Will look into it.